# Does redstone work on stair blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have been attempting to rebuild a "super smelter", following Tango Tek's design

However, for some reason, it won't work. The items to be smelted are not being distributed along the chain, like they should be.

I think it's because I'm using upside down stair blocks, next to the hoppers feeding the items... like so (forgive the crude drawing - on my mobile)

[image: Yay for freehand]

Basically, the stair block, in the original design, is meant to be a full block, which I believe locks the hoppers.

Is this the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Although you can place redstone on upside down stairs, stairs can't power any adjacent blocks. You'll have to use a full block. You experience the same behaviour when you use glowstone or slabs for example, because these blocks are considered transparent.

Comment: I tested it, and that's what it was :)